# groovy.json.JsonSlurper parse JSON

Tags: json, parsing, groovy, gradle

I'm trying to parse a JSON-File in my gradle task.

CODE:

```
def jsonFile = "../files/json/myJSON.json"
def list = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonFile)
```

JSON - FILE

```
{
   "prepare": {
       "installed": [],
       "uninstalled": []
   },
   "config": {
       "files": []
   }
}
```

But the code gives me the following exception:

```
Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading '.', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
```

And I don't understand why, I also validated my JSON-File on http://jsonlint.com/ and it says that it is a valid JSON!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above code is trying to parse the string `../files/json/myJSON.json` as JSON. Instead use:

```
def jsonFile = new File("../files/json/myJSON.json")
def map = new JsonSlurper().parse(jsonFile)
```

Comment: the path is longer, but I accidentally wrote it incorrect. I updated now.

Comment: Same problem regardless of the path.

Comment: It works now. But to your code I added .getText().
Danke schön!

Comment: for me didn't work without it. No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File) values:

Comment: My solution targets Groovy 2.2+/Gradle 2.0+. For Gradle 1.x, `.parse(jsonFile.text)` can be used.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305311/jsonslurper-execution-failure